# Прописание контроллеров для обработки запросов в соответствии с REST API

Tags: java, rest

Получил задание с обучения - Научиться писать контроллеры для обработки запросов в соответствии с REST API.
Что нужно сделать:
Укажите свойства и URL в API для каждой сущности.
Пропишите полностью форматы REST JSON API для приложения ToDoList. (Создание дела, удаление дела, обновление дела, получение списка, удаление всего списка). Настройте работу с данными потокобезопасно.

Все это делаю в Java, без JavaScript. Тестирую запросы используя прогу Talend API.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Методы Создания дела (Тип запроса POST), и метод получения списка (Тип запроса GET) работают и тестируются, есть вопросы по остальным методам, а именно  "Тип запроса PUT —
Обновление" и "Тип запроса DELETE - удаление".  Может есть какие предложение по тому или иному методу, как его правильно прописать? Учу Java недолго, поэтом просьба не смеяться)

```
package main;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import response.Book;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class BookController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List <Book> list() {
        return Storage.getAllBooks();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public int add(Book book){
        return Storage.addBook(book);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity get(@PathVariable int id) {
        Book book = Storage.getBook(id);
        if (book == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(book, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}



package main;
import response.Book;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Storage {

    private static int currentId = 1;
    private static HashMap<Integer, Book> books = new HashMap<Integer, Book>();

    public static List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        ArrayList<Book> booksList = new ArrayList<Book>();
        booksList.addAll(books.values());
        return booksList;
    }

    public static int addBook(Book book) {
        int id = currentId++;
        book.setId(id);
        books.put(id,book);
        return id;
    }

    public static Book getBook(int bookId) {
        if (books.containsKey(bookId)) {
            return books.get(bookId);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Удаление обычно только удаляет, не возвращает список оставшихся объектов. В принципе имеет смысл его void сделать.

Comment: да, мой метод удаления, нечего не удаляет)  ну а возврат списка я сделал, что бы сразу видеть при запросе удалилось или нет